# Display error using both search bar and autocomplete (materialize CSS)

Tags: html, css, frontend, materialize

I have some trouble setting up a materialize search bar (https://materializecss.com/navbar.html) that includes autocomplete (https://materializecss.com/autocomplete.html) for my website.

The autocomplete seems to "overwrite" the display of the search icon. If you do a "select all" you will see that the icon has turned white and is not aligned anymore.

Here is my `index.html` file so far:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper white">
      <form action="results" method="post">
        <div class="input-field">
          <input class="autocomplete" id="search" name="q" type="search"/>
          <label class="label-icon" for="search"><i class="material-icons">search</i></label>
          <i class="material-icons">close</i>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.autocomplete');
        var instances = M.Autocomplete.init(elems, {
                data: {
        "Apple": null,
        "Microsoft": null,
        "Google": 'https://placehold.it/250x250'
      },
          minLength: 1,
          limit:5
        });
      });
    </script>
</html>
```

I also figured out that with no data in the autocomplete js, the display of the search bar remain "normal".

Does anyone knows how or has solved this issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Over-ride these two things from `input-field label` class.

```
.input-field label {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px) !important;
    transform: translateY(0px) !important;
}
```

Use new versions of cdnjs.

```
 <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-rc.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```